# What happens if you have a gear ratio that’s infinitely high?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, kinetic-theory

What happens as the gear of a gearbox expands to infinity on either side?

If you had a material that could withstand the force and friction, could the last gear spin infinitely fast? What if it’s flipped, so one rotation of the first gear would cause the last gear to move less then a Planck length? If so, what would happen?

Comment: What is special about a Planck length?

Comment: Why do you have quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, and kinetic-theory tags for this question?

Comment: In other words: In a situation not covered by the laws of physics, what would the laws of physics predict?

Comment: Nothing would happen. You can't build it and even if you could, you would need infinite energy to put it motion.

Answer (score 1):

For gear ratios that are very small (i.e., the driven gear rotates much faster than the driver gear), the *angular speed* of the driven gear increases, not the speed. The product of the angular speed and the radius of the gear $(\omega r)$ indicates the translational speed of a tooth of a gear. $\omega r$ is constant for all teeth in the system. While their is no limit on the angular speed of the driven gear, any tooth on it can have a translational speed only as fast as a tooth on the driver gear. Hence, we do not violate special relativity.

For a system with a very large gear ratio (i.e., the driven gear rotates much slower than the driver gear), again, their are no limits on the angular speed of the driven gear. There is no minimum angular speed that the gear can't go below. However, by virtue of $\omega r$ being constant, any tooth on the driven gear can only have a translational speed as low as a tooth on the driver gear. But this doesn't matter.

Because your conception of the Planck length is flawed. Just because something travels slow enough doesn't mean that it covers a distance lesser than the Planck length in a given amount of time. With all due respect, I suggest that you read a bit more about the topic before asking such questions.